# Django gotchas: 1.5 vs. the rest (when learning from books/tutorials)?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Django 1.5 now supports Python 3 as per their [announcement](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/python3/). I have just started learning Python 3 and am about to play around with Django 1.5. However, most of the tutorials/books etc., deal with Django v1.1 onwards (to v1.4). Now that v1.5 is released what are some of the 'gotchas' to watch out for that may exist in the different versions of Django? (Or does it not matter?)

Comment: Moderator: Please migrate to appropriate forum if the need be.

Comment: This is not suitable for any of the main sites, but your question is welcome [on chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python).